# Specifying bit values: b'1' vs 1 vs true

Tags: mysql

From my tests, all 3 ways work for updating my bit(1) column. Similarly, b'0', 0 and false, all these update my bit(1) column the same.

So can i use any of these 3 ways for putting value in my bit(1) column?

Comment: `b'1` and `1` are the same thing, and in a numeric context MySQL treats `true` as `1`, and similarly for the opposites, so yes. You pretty much answered your own question anyway...

Comment: In your first sentence you wrote you could use these 3 ways to update your bit(1) field. Then why do you ask if you could any of these 3 ways to update your bit column?

Comment: @Shadow Because https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/bit-type.html only talked about the b'value' format. So i thought that the other two ways may not be officially supported and may break in future.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/bit-value-literals.html and https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/boolean-literals.html

Comment: Using different datatypes causes implicit type convertion (and sometimes it can differs from one which you need). Avoid it if it is possible. In this particular case - use literals of BIT datatype `b'1'` everywhere, when it is possible.